Bitcoin URI not working in multiple browsers?
Bitcoin URIs don't appear to work correctly in Brave (1.69.153), Safari (15.4), or Firefox (129.0.2).
I tested with the URI here: https://tails.net/donate/
(Works on mobile [iOS with Tangent wallet] ... but not on Desktop with multiple wallets tested.)
What's wrong?

URI handling is done by the operating system, not by the browser. Software that will handle a URI scheme must register with the OS so that it knows what software to launch when a URI is clicked. The method for registering depends on the OS.
If a URI is not being handled with the correct software, it is highly likely that the software you want to be launched is not properly registering with the OS. If you want a more detailed answer, you would need to tell us what wallet software you are trying to use, and what operating system you are using.
